# How do i access a simple txt file in an Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am creating an app where I list teachers and all the things they do at my school. I have 3 files, a class Teacher, which is an object that holds 7 string variables, a TeacherList class where i take the .txt file and extract my data from it in order to form the teachers. This is where my problem lies, where should i put the file? Heres the TeacherList code:

```
package com.mthebron.mthapp;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TeacherList {
public static Teacher[] MakeList() throws FileNotFoundException{
    Teacher[] teachers=new Teacher[71]; 
    File list=new File("C:/Users/Gareth/Desktop/TeacherInformation.txt");
    Scanner iScanner=new Scanner(list);
    StringBuilder teachersBuilder=new StringBuilder();
    while(iScanner.hasNext()) {
        teachersBuilder.append(iScanner.nextLine());
        teachersBuilder.append("\n");
    }
    String fullList=teachersBuilder.toString();
    String[] seperatedList=fullList.split("'");
    String[] blah=seperatedList[0].split("\n");
    String temp=blah[0].substring(3, 9);    
    String name=temp;
    String department=blah[1];
    String planning=blah[2];
    String club=blah[3];
    String sport=null;
    String email=blah[5];
    String website=null;
    teachers[0]=new Teacher(name, department, planning, club, sport, email, website);
    System.out.println(teachers[0].getSportsCoached());
    for (int i = 1; i < seperatedList.length; i++) {
        blah=seperatedList[i].split("\n");
        name=blah[1];
        department=blah[2];
        if (blah[3].equals("null")) {
            planning=null;
        }else planning=blah[3];
        if (blah[4].equals("null")) {
            sport=null;
        }else sport=blah[4];
        if (blah[5].equals("null")) {
            club=null;
        }else club=blah[5];
        if (blah[6].equals("null")) {
            email=null;
        }else email=blah[6];
        if (blah[7].equals("null")) {
            website=null;
        }else website=blah[7];
        teachers[i]=new Teacher(name, department, planning, sport, club, email, website);
    }
    return teachers;
}
```

Where should i put the file and will it still be able to work as a file object?

Answer (score 1):

If you dont know where to put the file you can simply say

```
File list = new File("TeacherInformation.txt")
```

and it will save it locally, you can access it the same way

Comment: well where would "locally" be, in like what folder of the android project?

Answer (score 0):

Is it a fixed file or are you adding to it?  If fixed, put in the assets folder.  Something like...

```
Scanner iScanner=new Scanner(getAssets().open("TeacherInformation.txt"));
```

Comment: when i added this line, i get an error that says that getAssets isnt a method

Comment: also the file is fixed, and i added it to the assets folder

Comment: You need a "Context".  I was assuming you were calling directly from your Activity.  See here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets()